# SFML Audio not Working

Tags: c++, audio, sfml, openal

I was using SFML earlier and I decided to play around with the audio settings. I made an instance of sf::Music and tried to play a sound. However I got an error that came up saying 
"The program can't start because openal32.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." I am making this as a project for the Ludum Dare so if this is a common problem I don't really want to have to use this. First off, where do I get openal32.dll? Is this a common problem? And what is an alternative that I can use in c++ for playing audio? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[OpenAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL) is an audio API that SFML is using internally. You have to make users install the OpenAL `dll`s, but the official site appears to be offline. You can try googling for a working link to download the OpenAL package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenAL-Soft instead:

http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal.html

It also supports HRTF for binaural headphones. You can also package it with your application (LGPL). You might have to rename soft_oal.dll to OpenAL.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but if someone has the same problem here is the solution:

Go to your SFML folder `sfml-version/bin/` and then copy all dlls to your project folder